# Batch change modified/created dates?

Tags: copy, metadata, nas

I recently bought new hard drives for my NAS. This means that I'm copying all the data off the NAS, upgrading it, and then moving the data back.

I've gotten as far as copying the data from the NAS, but every file's modified/created date has been changed to when it was copied (today).

Is there a way, keeping in mind that I have the original data, to batch update the modified/created dates on the copied files without having to copy them over again (we're talking over a terabyte of data)?

Comment: Seems like this question might be better suited for ServerFault

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention the NAS model?
You do not mention the HDD filesystem?
Is it both files and folders that are effected? Normally I just see it with folders.

I would look into:

- Robocopy (windows CLI)
- Xcopy (windows CLI)
- Total Commander (windows GUI)

Robocopy can do a lot of fancy stuff with files and permissions.

On my Synology it went quite smooth doing this with the web-api on the box, with the OLD HDD attached with USB.